# Dropped a rubber stopper in the engine bay of new vehicle

Tags: preventive-maintenance

I recently bought a 2022 Chevy Equinox and cracked the hood for the first time. While doing so I mistakenly forced a hood rubber stopper loose, that fell somewhere in the engine bay. I looked around for it with a flashlight but couldn't locate it. Later, I drove the vehicle for a few minutes as I assumed that might reveal any potential problems, and there didn't seem to be any.

I assume that it's likely not a problem if I can't locate it or confirm it fell to the ground, but wanted to run this problem by actual experts. Should I make an effort to get it out? What's the worst that could happen in this scenario?

Comment: What exactly was the "rubber stopper" for ... what is its purpose?

Comment: It was connected to the underside of the hood at the front. I'm guessing it was there to lessen the impact of closing the hood. There is another one intact on the other side. I believe the more immediate problem is it falling into the engine bay

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the rubber stopper that fell into the engine bay.  Although I would replace it.  It is there for a reason - to protect the body when closing the hood. 
 Maybe go to the dealer where you bought the car and tell them your story.  Since the rubber stopper should not fall off when you open your hood maybe they will provide you a new one at no charge since the part is cheap and it is a brand new car.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't readily find it and you've not seen smoke from under the hood, realistically there's not going to be an issue. More than likely it's wedged in some place you can't see (where you'll find it 5 years from now and say, "Hey, that's where you've been hiding"). Either that, or its already fallen out. Either way, no issue.

It sounds from your description, this is a rubber bumper which allows the hood to be tight without rattling or having metal-on-metal contact. They usually are adjustable, one way or another, which makes it so you can adjust the body line of the hood to where it matches the top of the fender. If this is what it is, there'll be no real short term problems with the piece missing. You'll want to replace it as soon as you can though. This will prevent the metal contact I stated above, which causes wear, as well as a spot where rust can start forming after it's worn through the paint. As Mike H. stated in comments, replacement of such should be relatively cheap. Unless it just "fell off", I doubt the dealership is going to replace it for free, but I doubt they'll charge you an arm and a leg for you to purchase it.